# Detect table updates on OracleDB

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, etl

Say we have a table in oracledb called `fruits`:

```
id fruit
1  banana
2  mango
3  melon
```

Imagine this table is being overwitten completely, say every Friday for example, the column `id` is the primary key.

```
id fruit
1  watermelon
2  strawberry
3  coconut
```

In this case, I imagine keeping track of the changes in this table through a primary key is impossible, since the primary key itself is being overwritten. Is there a particular way to keep track of the changes in this table, maybe through oracle's internal tables ?
My main goal is to monitor this database in question which in reality is an operational data store, fetch the changes when they are applied, apply some transformations and store the data in a data warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture changes when they happen for ETL, you may want to look at [materialized views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B) and [materialized view logs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW-LOG.html#GUID-13902019-D044-4B79-9EB4-1F60652D037B). You would create the MV in your data warehouse (or an intermediary ETL database) and the log on the table in your OLTP database.

Alternatively, you could create triggers on the OLTP table that write changes to an audit table as they happen. The ETL process could use that audit table as a basis.

Both methods have consequences for database performance, as they add extra recursive inserts to every commit. Whether this is acceptable or not will depend on the performance characteristics of the database server(s).

Comment: this is very helpful, thanks. In your opinion, what is the advantage to move to an intermediary database, often called staging server ?

Comment: The advantage would be that you can do whatever you need without impacting the production database. As you indicate, it should sit on a different server, so it does not compete with the production, but it could just as well be a separate schema in your DW database if that server is powerful enough.